# Create index on a column with only 2 distinct values

Tags: sql, database-indexes

I have a table with millions of records.

One of the column has only 2 values '0' and '1'.

I am only concerned about the records where the column value is '0' and do some processing off of those records.

Considering the number of records containing value '0' will be around in the hundreds would it be wise to create an index on that column.

Since then the index will just have 2 values '0' with hundreds of refrences to the actual records and '1' with references to its cooresponding millions of records.

Here since I dont care about '1' and its references, should I be using an index in the first place?

Comment: which RDMS are you using? In SQL server you could use filtered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In an engineering field, including software engineering, you should measure the results, instead of guessing (or asking people on the internet to tell you the right thing to do).

You should use EXPLAIN to find out how your SQL database will optimize different queries, given the value you search for.

Since you have an imbalanced number of rows with 0 versus rows with 1, you're right that there is probably going to be a big difference in how the database optimizes queries that search for one or the other value.

The overhead of reading the index would likely be a waste if you're searching for 1 given that it would visit 99% of the rows anyway. So a good optimizer should skip the index and just read the table directly, discarding the minority of rows that don't match.

But if you search for the minority value 0, the optimizer should be able to tell that using the index will be beneficial.

Use EXPLAIN to verify this. Try out both queries (searching for 0 and searching for 1) with EXPLAIN and see what the difference is in the optimizer's plan.

I'm being vague about the syntax of EXPLAIN because you have decided not to be specific about which brand of SQL database you're using. You only tagged your question "sql" and "database-indexes" but not "sql-server" or "mysql" or "postgresql" or whatever you are using.

EXPLAIN is not part of the standard SQL language, so each database implements EXPLAIN slightly differently. The specific answer will depend on which SQL database you use.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Detalii_Meciuri(
    DetaliiID int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    MeciID int FOREIGN KEY (MeciID)
    REFERENCES Meciuri(MeciID),
    Categoria_1 int not null check (Categoria_1 = 0 or Categoria_1 = 1) ,
    Categoria_2 int not null check (Categoria_2 = 0 or Categoria_2 = 1) ,
    Categoria_3 int not null check (Categoria_3 = 0 or Categoria_3 = 1) ,
    Categoria_4 int not null check (Categoria_4 = 0 or Categoria_4 = 1) ,
    Categoria_5 int not null check (Categoria_5 = 0 or Categoria_5 = 1) ,
    Puncte_Echipa_A int not null check (Puncte_Echipa_A > 0),
    Puncte_Echipa_B int not null check (Puncte_Echipa_B > 0),
);
```

Comment: I think you may have accidentally answered the wrong question